# ansible playbook run a task only once

Tags: ansible

I need to run a task ,set a flag and the second time the play runs run the task only if the flag is not set

Play at a later stage

```
- name: Dump all databases
  mysql_db:
    state: dump
    name: all
    target: /root/mysql_all.sql
  when:  ansible_local.mysql.replication.setup is not defined

- name: create directory for ansible custom facts
  file: state=directory recurse=yes path=/etc/ansible/facts.d
- name: install custom fact stating mysql is setup
  template:
    src: mysql.fact.j2
    dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/mysql.fact
```

The problem is that the fist time this play runs its throwing an error.

```
FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_local.mysql.replication.setup is not defined' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_local.mysql.replication.setup is not defined): 'ansible_local' is undefined
```

What is the best way to run a task only in the first run and skip for subsequent runs.

Answer (score 1):

you should make a task prior that registers if `/root/mysql_all.sql` exists then add it to your `when` clause.

Example:

```
- name: check if dump exists
  stat: 
    path: /root/mysql_all.sql
  register: mysqldump

- name: Dump all databases
  mysql_db:
    state: dump
    name: all
    target: /root/mysql_all.sql
  when:
    - ansible_local.mysql.replication.setup is not defined
    - mysqldump.stat.exists == true

- name: create directory for ansible custom facts
  file: state=directory recurse=yes path=/etc/ansible/facts.d
- name: install custom fact stating mysql is setup
  template:
    src: mysql.fact.j2
    dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/mysql.fact
```

Comment: The check fo the fact is still failing as the variable is undefined. But I think to touch a unique file the first time its run and running only when the file doesn't exist as you suggested would be the easy way around.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to utilize the fact cache. When enabled, you can set cacheable facts in your play and check for them.

Fact caching always takes place. There are various fact cache plug-ins available of which the memory plug-in is the default, and json file and redis cache are the most popular. You can only set one plug-in. Refer to
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html

When you want to explore with the json file you can set the environment variables as follows:

```sh
export ANSIBLE_CACHE_PLUGIN=jsonfile
export ANSIBLE_CACHE_PLUGIN_CONNECTION="~/ansiblefactcache"
```

In your play book you can check for facts and set them as cacheable, Refer to
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html

A small example `playbook.yaml`:

```yaml
- name: Example Fact Cache Playbook
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false # the default is true; it gathers various host facts
  tasks:
    - name: Runs when examplefact equals something
      debug:
        msg: "Runs when examplefact equals something"
      when: ansible_facts['examplefact'] is defined and ansible_facts['examplefact'] == "something"
    - name: Does not run when examplefact equals something
      debug:
        msg: "does not run when examplefact equals something"
      when: ansible_facts['examplefact'] is not defined or ansible_facts['examplefact'] != "something"
    - name: Set the examplefact to something
      set_fact: 
        examplefact: "something"
        cacheable: true
```

Note the usage of the `cacheable` instruction. When `true` the fact goes into the cache.

After having run this small playbook you will notice the creation of a `localhost` file in your home's subfolder `ansiblefactcache` which contains your cached facts.

Also note the usage of the `gather_facts` instruction. The default being `true` will scan your machine for various details such as environment variables, network details, etc. All are cached. You can play with it and see the `localhost` file being populated with it.

You can also try to edit the `localhost` file yourself or even delete it and run the play again.

I used the following inventory file `inventory.yaml`:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
```

And I run `ansible` as follows:
`ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventory.yaml -vvv`

First run yields the following:

```
PLAY [Example Fact Cache Playbook] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Runs when examplefact equals something] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Does not run when examplefact equals something] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "does not run when examplefact equals something"
}

TASK [Set the examplefact to something] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
```

Second run yields the following:

```
PLAY [Example Fact Cache Playbook] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Runs when examplefact equals something] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Runs when examplefact equals something"
}

TASK [Does not run when examplefact equals something] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Set the examplefact to something] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
```